# Probabilistic inequality for an antisymmetric function

Tags: integration, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable with $\mathbb P(-1 \leq X \leq 1) = 1$. Does $\mathbb E(X) \geq 0$ imply
$$\mathbb E[X(1-|X|)] \geq 0?$$
The function is antysymmetric around $0$ and has more probability mass on the positive side. Intuitively, it should be correct.

If not, is it true if I assume $\mathbb E(X) > 0$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X$ take the values $-\frac  1 2$ with probability $\frac  1 4$ and $1 $ with probability $\frac  3 4$. You can check that $EX >0$ but $E(X(1-|X|) <0$.

Comment: Ok thank you! Would have been nice, if the inequality is true :/

Answer (score 4):

The answer is no.

A simple counter-example is letting $X\equiv 1$.
meaning, $X$ is a constant random variable equal to 1.

We get $$\mathbb E[X(1-\vert X\vert)] = \mathbb E[X(1-\vert 1\vert)] = 0$$

Comment: Ok sorry, I was a bit imprecise. I don't need strict inequalities. What if I replace all $<$ by $\leq$?.

Comment: Again a bit imprecise... I meant all $>$ by $\geq$. I will edit the question.